# June 2012 Community Moderator Election RESULTS

Tags: discussion, moderators

All of this [election madness](https://stackoverflow.com/election/3) is now at an end, your votes have been cast and counted and the three winners have their shiny new diamonds:

[image: Brad Larson] [image: George Stocker] [image: ThiefMaster]

Please give them a warm welcome, and do your best to be gentle as you introduce them to their new roles.

Comment: GORTOOOOOOOOOK!

Comment: Congratulations to all! The community has made excellent choices.

Comment: My hat off to your hard work and dedication and I'm glad it's not me.

Comment: "99,626 voters were eligible; 4,426 voted" Wow, that turnout is terrible.

Comment: Congratulations! Nice to see all the three I voted for :) I wish you all the best for your work!

Comment: So where do I send the bribes to keep my voting ring under wraps?  :)

Comment: Good luck next time @minitech :(

Comment: @daxim That's the echo chamber effect, working as-designed. Enjoy it!

Comment: There were so many good choices, it almost didn't matter to me whether the ones I voted for won. Congratulations to all three (especially Brad "third time's the charm" Larson)!

Comment: @YannisRizos He's [not the first](http://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock)

Comment: @Michael I know, [PHP devs are getting diamonds everywhere](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tags/php/topusers)...

Comment: Insert comment stating outrage at low voter turnout typical of of most large scale voting systems

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congrats! And good luck :)

Comment: It should be noted than they aren't full moderators yet, they each  need a MSO question calling them evil Nazis before they can be considered full members of team diamond.

Comment: Congratulations and my condolences.

Comment: Many Many Congratulations guys.

Comment: This has exactly 42 up votes. **NOBODY TOUCH ANYTHING**

Comment: @TimPost: Oops, undoing that now!

Comment: Great job, now get to work. I have a dozen comment flags, three wiki edits and two NARQ flags pending. j/k Congrats!

Comment: Awesome! Excellent choices!

Comment: Wonderful, you are now part of the tribe!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congrats **BradLarson**, **TheifMaster** and **GeorgeStocker**. Welcome you all.

Comment: Heartily Congratulations to new community moderators

Comment: Congrats guys! great choice community! :)

Comment: hearty welcome 2 the folks who deserve it ;)
now the game of moderation begins, responsibilities at reasonable cost..

Comment: i want to congratulate the the top three and also want to say one thing to the guys who are not selected that you all are also good and never less than these three. So enjoy the life and guide the new people like me on SO. :-)

Comment: Good Choice, most of the guys shared my choice. WOW. Congrates...:)

Comment: Congrats **BradLarson, TheifMaster and GeorgeStocker**. I had voted for BradLarson and GeorgeStocker so i found my vote helpful :)

Comment: Congratulations to all winners :)

Comment: Congrats and do best work ahed :)

Comment: @YannisRizos: Actually I don't do PHP anymore. Switched to Python.

Comment: Nothing wrong with spaghetti ;p

Comment: @ThiefMaster Congratulations!

Comment: congrats to @ThiefMaster and Brad Larson and GeorgeStocker......

Comment: Wow, my three choices! I feel in tune with the community :)

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new moderator overlords!

Comment: Congratulations to all :)

Comment: @Yannis Rizos: He wasn't the first, you know. There have been a few.

Comment: Congratulations guys !

Comment: Congrats guys, don't u have any work to do?

Comment: Congratulations!! :)

Comment: Congrats!!! all the moderators:)

Comment: Best wishes to all three of you! I had wanted to vote (but 145 rep :) ), and I'm happy to see that three great people won the election and will be moderating SO.

Comment: congrats winners .. !

Comment: Let the moderation begin!

Comment: Welcome and Congratulations!

Comment: 99,626 voters were eligible, 60,208 visited the site during the election, 19,479 visited the election page, and only 4,426 voted.. That's something interesting (or uninteresting ?)

Comment: @blasteralfred: Isn't that what daxim already said?

Comment: Congratulations to all of you.

Comment: Congratulations to all of our new moderators

Comment: @daxim: Particularly odd that we have only 4% turnout when they give a silver badge for it.  Maybe the token economy needs work, or the communication mechanism wasn't effective.  Or maybe 4% is pretty damn good.

Comment: @TimLehner 4% is damn great! And Congratulations to all 3!

Comment: I for one would have been quite content with six or seven of the finalists as moderators -- most have made a good impression on me in the past -- electing only three feels like an unfortunate waste of goodwill and effort.

Comment: Kudos to all! :)

Comment: Congratulations and good luck to our new moderators!

Comment: Many Many Congratulations and good luck!!! I voted for these three and they are selected... yipeeeee!!!

Comment: Welcome and good luck... Great, will be seeing my post as soon as it appears

Comment: Cheers to our new moderators. Hope you give the best for the Community.. Good luck guys..

Comment: Greetings and Congratulations to our Newly elected Moderators :)

Comment: Congrats and Best of luck !

Comment: many many Congrats **BradLarson**, **TheifMaster** and **GeorgeStocker**. Welcome you all, i am happy that my choice is here.. and now be ready to catch my flags.. and plz guide me, because **one day i would like be there**..see you on SO

Comment: Congrats guys...and all the best

Comment: @TimPost `This has exactly 42 up votes. NOBODY TOUCH ANYTHING`

 dont tell us what to do, upvoted!

Comment: @blasteralfred Isn't it better that people looked and didn't vote, rather than looking and voting randomly to get a badge, or because they could?

Comment: Congratz !!! All my votes hits the bullseye :)

Comment: Yay, congratulations to each one of you! :)

Comment: We don't do warm welcomes, we expect them to get to work.

Comment: @daxim I know! There should be much more participation in the elections. If you look here <http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136944/should-the-primary-phase-of-the-election-be-eliminated>, someone suggests that the primary phase might confuse some users by making them think that they had cast their actual vote. This would mostly effect users not from the U.S., and if you look here <http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25838/what-countries-have-the-most-stack-overflow-users-per-capita>, you can see that the SO community is indeed very diverse. Makes me think...

Comment: Congratulations to all!! Especially @ThiefMaster.

Comment: Congratulations!!! Give your same effort to us.....

Comment: Congrats guys! Good job.

Comment: Congrats!!! Good Luck! Have FUN! :D

Comment: Can I have a badge for voting for the 3 winners?

Comment: Coonnngrattsss.

Comment: Wowwww...Nice choice...No one can misuse StackOverflow.These three wont allow..:)All the very best..

Comment: Congrats!!! Welcome, treat our questions well!!

Comment: @minitech Really wanted you to win this one. Good luck next time.

Comment: Congratulations to all! and I'm happy to see that three great people won the election and will be moderating..

Comment: Congrats to all.. :-)

Comment: When posting **June 2012 Community Moderator Election RESULTS** here, it will better to give **percentage of votes** for top three candiates and **votes they get** in post itself...

Comment: congrats!!!! to all

Comment: Congratulations and do what are you paid for! :D (just kidding :) )

Comment: I wish "Suckers" had more characters.

Comment: Congratz You Guys!

Answer (score 94):

[OpenSTV](http://www.openstv.org/) reports:

```
Loading ballots from file stackoverflow-com-2012-election-results.blt.
Ballot file contains 10 candidates and 4426 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 4426 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for Stack Overflow Moderator Election 2012 using Meek STV.
10 candidates running for 3 seats.

 R|minitech     |Brad Larson  |Sathya       |George Stocke|Moshe        |ThiefMaster  |awoodland    
  |             |             |             |r            |             |             |             
  |-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------
  |Andrew Barber|slugster     |Dennis       |Exhausted    |Surplus      |Threshold    
  |             |             |             |             |             |             
====================================================================================================
 1|   393.000000|  1226.000000|   273.000000|   574.000000|    95.000000|   877.000000|   405.000000
  |   187.000000|   164.000000|   232.000000|     0.000000|   119.499999|  1106.500001
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. Candidate Brad Larson has reached the threshold and is elected.
====================================================================================================
 2|   408.497889|  1106.500554|   279.335615|   597.685453|    99.386195|   906.826126|   423.519490
  |   194.212854|   169.458376|   236.093782|     4.483666|     1.121470|  1105.379084
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Brad Larson, 0.902529.
====================================================================================================
 3|   419.277657|  1120.038489|   290.017912|   608.465221|             |   922.190720|   433.299258
  |   199.797680|   178.555847|   243.678608|    10.678608|    16.208140|  1103.830349
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Moshe and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
====================================================================================================
 4|   457.544780|  1138.991598|   303.310325|   631.244989|             |   948.652785|   450.273968
  |   215.869861|             |   263.555847|    16.555847|    36.630559|  1102.361039
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating slugster and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
====================================================================================================
 5|   484.104316|  1179.605403|   317.285035|   664.707054|             |   993.089560|   476.100627
  |             |             |   282.335615|    28.772390|    80.298500|  1099.306903
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Andrew Barber and transferring votes. All losing candidates are
  | eliminated.
====================================================================================================
 6|   496.145968|  1099.307244|   322.507180|   681.540792|             |  1015.206880|   490.661196
  |             |             |   286.329020|    34.301720|     1.382673|  1097.924571
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Brad Larson, 0.841092.
====================================================================================================
 7|   542.052864|  1134.633108|   363.414076|   717.812056|             |  1077.067224|   515.979012
  |             |             |             |    75.041660|    46.893522|  1087.739586
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Dennis and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
====================================================================================================
 8|   604.548840|  1190.145180|             |   760.036768|             |  1155.039924|   547.157172
  |             |             |             |   169.072116|   216.721160|  1064.231972
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Sathya and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
  | Candidate ThiefMaster has reached the threshold and is elected.
====================================================================================================
 9|   646.798688|  1085.755858|             |   800.387034|             |  1097.274262|   581.726734
  |             |             |             |   214.057424|    77.058830|  1052.985645
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Brad Larson, 0.752108 and ThiefMaster, 0.921382.
====================================================================================================
10|   662.844684|  1062.859601|             |   814.086271|             |  1061.074550|   593.285435
  |             |             |             |   231.849459|    26.858879|  1048.537636
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Brad Larson, 0.729408 and ThiefMaster, 0.884193.
====================================================================================================
11|   746.154478|  1215.006828|             |   891.865133|             |  1150.253436|             
  |             |             |             |   422.720125|   363.620326|  1000.819969
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating awoodland and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
====================================================================================================
12|   827.292517|  1028.081646|             |   964.246561|             |  1047.215248|             
  |             |             |             |   559.164028|   141.878906|   966.708994
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Brad Larson, 0.600825 and ThiefMaster, 0.769325.
====================================================================================================
13|   860.295372|   979.907284|             |   991.140324|             |   978.655437|             
  |             |             |             |   616.001583|    92.204230|   952.499605
  |-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Brad Larson, 0.564958 and ThiefMaster, 0.710182. Candidate George Stocker has reached
  | the threshold and is elected.

Winners are Brad Larson, George Stocker, and ThiefMaster.
```

Comment: @sth [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english)

Comment: @sth I will get back at you when I _fully_ understand how Meek's STV works. Expect a long wait ;)

Comment: Actually, that depends on the threshold, and HOW you voted. Your full vote counts towards your first person, until that person gets elected. Then you get a refund percentage towards your second choice. Then it repeats. So your first vote may get 0.01% of your vote, or it may get 100% of your vote, or it may get 7.5% of your vote. The remainder is of course, if your first vote isn't eliminated right away. So if, in this election, you had voted Moshe,Brad,Thief you would have lost all vote when Moshe got eliminated first.

Comment: By now I'm confused and not sure anymore what I'm talking about...

Comment: Only a bunch of weird people like us can come up with a scheme like this...

Comment: @Erno Well, we didn't come up with it, [Thomas Hare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Hare_(political_scientist)) did in the 19th century...

Comment: @YannisRizos - and we decided to use it in the 21st century... I always found the English election system pretty strange.

Comment: geesh, trying to figure out these results is driving me bonkers! it would be silly to ask for george's threshold right... O_o... threshold? what?

Comment: @Joe Brad, George and ThiefMaster won, and that's all you need to know /waves hand

Comment: This seams like an alternative voting system. This youtube video explains it perfectly: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Y3jE3B8HsE

Comment: Am I right in saying the election did go Brad, Thiefmaster, George in that order then?

Comment: @Mat Brad was elected in round 2, ThiefMaster in round 8 and George in round 13, so yes you got the order right, although the order is extremely uninteresting for those elected. awoodland is fourth and minitech fifth, in case there's a call up.

Comment: Regression analysis on reputation / votes correlation anybody?

Comment: Does it mean that on average we have about 4500 active users on SO?

Comment: @JSantos, that is exactly the system. It is sometimes called trickle-down voting.

Comment: **"All losing candidates are eliminated."** what a lovely phrase

Comment: ...uh, ok. I'll take your word for it that this is all correct haha

Comment: @gnat It does have a very Bond-villain-esque tone to it.

Comment: WOOOOOOOO! DIAMONDS!!!!

Comment: Who pays the hitman for the unlucky candidates?

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Forget the hitman... I think death by COBOL or RPG would be more fitting.

Comment: @M.Babcock At least COBOL is just inhumane.

Comment: I for one welcome our moderator overloards

Comment: @YannisRizos: Just to confirm, Brad was elected on first preferences in the _first_ round.

Comment: @MarkHurd You're right I realised the mistake after posting the comment, but couldn't edit it any more. Anyways, the correct results are in the answer and it clearly says Brad was elected in the first round.